# Opciones de margen en Pdf con Rotativa Mvc

Tags: c#, mvc, pdf, margin, rotativa

He estado leyendo que para poner o quitar los márgenes de un PDF se utiliza la siguiente línea:

```
PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0,0,0,0)
```

Pero, cuando yo las ingreso me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
'ViewAsPDF' no contiene una definición para 'PageMargins'
```

¿Alguna solución?

Este es el código completo:

```
return new ViewAsPdf("Pdf48", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud))
                    {
                        CustomSwitches = "--header-html " + _headerUrl + " --header-spacing 0 " +
                                 "--footer-html " + _footerUrl + " --footer-spacing 0",
                       PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0,0,0,0)                
                    };
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando la misma versión de la librería que el ejemplo del que te estás basando?

Comment: Sí, ya lo solucioné :) Gracias @fredyfx

Comment: En la parte inferior hay una caja de texto para colocar la respuesta, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan un escenario igual o similar. Recuerda marcarla como aceptada en 24 horas haciendo click en el check verde del costadoo de la respuesta :D

Comment: Sí, sí. Eso estoy por hacer @fredyfx

Comment: muchas gracias bro :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución:**

```
return new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf48", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud))
                    {
                        RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions
                        {
                            CustomSwitches = "--header-html " + _headerUrl + " --header-spacing 0 " +
                                "--footer-html " + _footerUrl + " --footer-spacing 0",
                            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        }
                };
```